# how to eliminiate the duplicates from SQL table which has two type of data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, database-normalization

I have a table in my database called `email`. this will store the `email address` of all `customers` based on the `type of email` they provide. there is a column `email type` which tells the email is business or personal. when a customer provide business email address we will update it under `type business` and keep the personal email type as `Null`. when we try to join this table with my query it gives me duplicate data in `email` column as the email table has two columns(one as `NULL`, other one has `email address`). I cannot give a condition where `emailaddress` is `not null` because there are customer who doesn't have provided any email address so both of their `emailtype` will be `null`. so those records will be avoided from my query. please help me how to pull the correct email address without pulling the deplicate

I have tried using the condition `where emailaddress is not null`. but the query result is avoiding the data where both the `emailtypes are null`

```
select distinct
c.rtlrcontractidentifier as RetailerID,
CT.Fullname as Fullname,
ad.address1 as Address,
ad.City,
ad.provinceorstate as State,
ad.postalcode as Zip
, e.emailaddress
from contract c
inner join siteidentification si on si.siteoid=c.siteoid
inner join consumer cs on cs.consumeroid=c.billingconsumeroid
inner join contact ct on ct.contactoid=cs.billingcontactoid
left  Join Address ad  on  ad.FKObjectOID = ct.contactOID  
and  ad.fktableobjectoid=1049
left join email e on e.contactoid=ct.contactoid
where c.rtlrcontractidentifier in('AG74113048'
)
```

I need to get the `emailaddress` which is updated but not with the duplicate(null). also should get the data where there is no `emailaddress` on both `emailtypes`.
[image]

Comment: Please provide some sample data to work on, and expected results.

Comment: provide your table schema, input data and expected output data

Comment: I have added screenshot of table

Answer (score 0):

What happened is that you have rows in email table, with contact_oid, and email_type
It is not specified, but I assume your email table:
contact_oid, email_type, email_address

For business emails, it will be email_type = 'B' and for personal emails, the email_type = NULL. To find only emails record that is available, instead of placing a WHERE on the email_type, use the contact_oid to determine if the row exists or not.
In this case, just changing the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN should work. If this is not the case, then provide some sample data to work on.

```
SELECT      DISTINCT
            c.rtlrcontractidentifier        AS RetailerID
            , ct.Fullname                   AS Fullname
--          , e.emailtype --> To show the email type
            , e.emailaddress
FROM        contracts               AS c
            INNER JOIN consumer     AS cs ON cs.consumeroid = c.billingconsumeroid
            INNER JOIN contact      AS ct ON ct.contactoid = cs.billingcontactoid
--> Change from LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN
            INNER JOIN email        AS e  ON e.contactoid = ct.contactoid
WHERE       c.rtlrcontractidentifier IN ('AG74113048');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that another way to avoid duplicates is to specify two columns for business email and personal email:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT
      c.rtlrcontractidentifier as RetailerID,
      .
      .
      .
      be.emailaddress as businesss_email,
      pe.emailaddress as personal_email
      FROM contract c
      .
      .
      .
      LEFT JOIN  email be on be.contactoid=ct.contactoid
      LEFT JOIN email pe on pe.contactoid=ct.contactoid
      WHERE c.rtlrcontractidentifier in('AG74113048') AND
         be.email_type = 'Business' AND
         pe.email_type = 'Personal'
```

If you don't like having the two columns, you should be able to combine them with:

```
       SELECT DISTINCT
      c.rtlrcontractidentifier as RetailerID,
      .
      .
      .
      ISNULL(be.emailaddress, pe.emailaddress) AS emailaddress
      FROM contract c
      .
      .
      .
      LEFT JOIN  email be on be.contactoid=ct.contactoid
      LEFT JOIN email pe on pe.contactoid=ct.contactoid
      WHERE c.rtlrcontractidentifier in('AG74113048') AND
         be.email_type = 'Business' AND
         pe.email_type = 'Personal'
```

In the above query, you will get the business email if it's not NULL, otherwise you will get the personal address.